# C# - How do I see what subclass a certain instance is when looking through a list of base instances?

Tags: c#, list, xna, base-class

I am developing a game as a school project using XNA. I'm trying to create a code in my "Entity" base class that checks what specific subclass of "Entity" that i'm currently colliding with.

This is what I've been trying to use so far:

*in "Entity"*

```
 protected Entity CheckCollisionWithEntity(Vector2 pos)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle((int)pos.X, (int)pos.Y, _texture.Width, _texture.Height - 1);

        foreach (Entity e in _entities)
        {
            if (r.Intersects(e.Collider))
            {
                if(e != this)
                return e;
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

*in "Player" (which is, like "Enemy", a subclass of "Entity")*

```
  if (CheckCollisionWithEntity(Position) is Enemy)
        {
            Game1.instance.reloadLevel();
        }
```

My problem is that when I collide with an "Enemy" instance - nothing happens.
I know for a fact that the "reloadLevel()" method works, and I have tried switching it out for debug code. 
What am I doing wrong here? Have I misunderstood the "is" reference?
The enemies Colliders are working for other less specific types of colission checking.

Comment: `CheckCollisionWithEntity` will exit, returning the first Entity found.  What if the Player is in collision with two or more Entities, and only one of them is an Enemy?

Comment: Return an IEnumerable<Entity> and use the power of LINQ with CheckCollisionsWithEntities( .. ).OfType<Enemy>()

Comment: @SirRufo I'm not familliar with this function, could you maybe specify how I would use it in my code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how one uses `is`, so the returned object must not be an `Enemy` object.

You stated you swapped in debug code - have you verified that the method is indeed returning an object that is or is derived from `Enemy`?  Step through your code and check what's being returned - perhaps your collision detection code doesn't work and you're always returning `null` (`null is someClass` will always evaluate to `false`).  Your method returns only the first `Entity` it determines as a collision - could a non-`Enemy` entity be detected prior to any `Enemy` entities?

Comment: Turns out my code was working, I was actually just forgetting to update the Enemy objects collider (I have 2 seperate colliders for physics and other game logic).